# Redirecting users to the facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

If I have an app on facebook that's pulling the content from http://example.com for instance, is there a way I can stop people visting the example.com site and instead redirect them to the facebook app page?

Comment: Upvoting.  Great question, I've wondered about this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kalvin is close. Props to Kalvin  :)

1. Setup your website to default to `index.html`
2. Move the real content of your site from `index.html` to `index-fb.html`
3. In index.html then place either the meta tag for redirection or just javascript for location.href='' script for redirection. The url to redirect to will be in the  `https://apps.facebook.com/{yourappname}` format.
4. In facebook, update the app settings canvas app url from `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/index-fb.html`

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is sending a POST variable called `signed_request` when the page is opened within a Fan Page Tab or the Canvas page of your App. Simply check if the POST variable is there and redirect to your App's Canvas page if not ;-)

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/) you can read a bit how the signed_request is used inside an App.

Comment: Thanks! Will have a go later on, I'll let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .htaccess or conf.d file on your Apache web server (or the rewrite rules in IIS) to give a 301 Permenant Redirect.

Assuming you have Apache:

1.) Log into the box using ssh or some terminal emmulation program

2.) cd /etc/httpd/conf.d

3.) Locate the the configuration file for your site, edit it using vi, emacs, nano, or some text editor

4.) See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) on how to write the rewrite rule.

Comment: The 301 won't work because of the iframe limitation through facebook, the app still needs to be able to view the site to pull the content in

Answer (score 0):

1) Pull your content from your website from a subfolder

2) Redirect them from the index.html using a meta tag:
   http://www.web-source.net/html_redirect.htm

A better way would be to check if the content is being displayed inside facebook and then redirect but I have no idea how to do that